# Where can I find how many audits I passed or failed?

Tags: support, review-audits

I was wondering if there is a way to know how many audits I failed and how many I passed on Stack Overflow?

Comment: You can follow the history and count each attempt. But if SE provides an easy list it encourages gaming the system. Besides as long as you have an occasional failed audit once in a while, there is nothing to worry about.

Comment: @ToonKrijthe thanks. The question came in the top on my mind this morning, while I was reviewing the "close" queue. The system asked me to make attention because the question, in its opinion, was spam. So I starting wandering if maybe too much failed audits could lead to this kind of alert

Comment: Too much failed audits leads to a week suspension.

Comment: so, in your opinion, the alert is not related ?

Comment: @Kedarnath, no today I passed all the audits but yesterday I failed one. I was banned once that's true

Comment: @blackbelt, Its my mistake. Sorry.

Comment: @Kedarnath no problem :)

Comment: blackbelt, that warning has nothing to do with whether or not you've failed audits, don't worry about it. It's just posts the system thinks might be spam + they add it to audits sometimes.